# How do I perform a exact match in man page?

Tags: regex, manpage

For exmaple, I open man page of `tar` and I want to locate `-z` quickly.

But when I type `/-z`, things like `-i, --ignore`**`-z`**`eros` also get matched. So I have to press `n` several times to reach `-z`.

However, I tried `/-z$` or `/^-z$` but neither works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` and `$` in this context refer to the start and end of a complete line - what you need is a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
/-z\b

   -z, --gzip, --gunzip, --ungzip
          Filter the archive through gzip(1).

   -Z, --compress, --uncompress
          Filter the archive through compress(1).
```

If you also want to exclude the upper case match as well, then see [Can I force `man` to do lower case sensitive matching?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124282/can-i-force-man-to-do-lower-case-sensitive-matching)

Comment: Did I misunderstand `^` and `$` or they are just different here in man page?

Comment: @Rick they mean the same in any line-based context - for example compare `echo 'foo bar' | sed -n '/^bar/p'` versus `echo 'foo bar' | sed -n '/\bbar/p'`

Answer (score 0):

A GUI alternative is to use this:

[image: man tar.png]

Click on the first link and then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> followed by `-z,` and you are greeted with:

[image: man tar -z.png]

Of course using CLI is faster for quick and dirty but for extensive reading I prefer the internet.

Comment: Ah I know this one. But sometimes it would be cubersome to open in brower. Thanks anyway.